# STM32F030 GPIO interrupt

Tags: stm32, stm32f0

Trying to get an interrupt on A3, to wake the cpu up from sleep on a rx char, but it's not firing.

What is it that defines which interrupt the GPIO pin will trigger? I can't find it in the reference manual

```
static void EXTI0_1_IRQHandler_Config(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef   GPIO_InitStructure;

  /* Enable GPIOA clock */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

  GPIO_InitStructure.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_RISING;
  GPIO_InitStructure.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStructure.Pin = GPIO_PIN_3;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure);

  /* Enable and set EXTI line 0 Interrupt to the lowest priority */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI0_1_IRQn, 2, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI0_1_IRQn);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interrupt functions are (briefly) described in Chapter 11 Interrpts and events, Section 11.1.3 Interrupt and exception vectors.

[image]

So, the interrupt number is `EXTI2_3_IRQn`, and you should define `EXTI2_3_IRQHandler()` to call `HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler()`.

**Some background**

There are a couple of steps involved in getting a callback function called when an interrupt request occurs.

Each interrupt request has an interrupt number assigned to it, see the Position entry in the table above. The number is defined by the hardware, the symbolic name is assigned somewhere in the machine headers.

```
typedef enum {
   [...]
   EXTI0_1_IRQn                = 5,      /*!< EXTI Line 0 and 1 Interrupt */
   EXTI2_3_IRQn                = 6,      /*!< EXTI Line 2 and 3 Interrupt */
   [...]
} IRQn_Type;
```

There is a corresponding function pointer in the vector table, which should contain the address of the handler function. This vector table is filled out in the startup module, which is called `startup_stm32f030x8.s` or something similar, and the linker configuration file ensures that the table ends up at the proper physical address when programming the flash.

```
g_pfnVectors:
  .word  _estack
  .word  Reset_Handler
  .word  NMI_Handler
  .word  HardFault_Handler
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  SVC_Handler
  .word  0
  .word  0
  .word  PendSV_Handler
  .word  SysTick_Handler
  .word  WWDG_IRQHandler                   /* Window WatchDog              */
  .word  0                                 /* Reserved                     */
  .word  RTC_IRQHandler                    /* RTC through the EXTI line    */
  .word  FLASH_IRQHandler                  /* FLASH                        */
  .word  RCC_IRQHandler                    /* RCC                          */
  .word  EXTI0_1_IRQHandler                /* EXTI Line 0 and 1            */
  .word  EXTI2_3_IRQHandler                /* EXTI Line 2 and 3            */
...
```

The entries are in fixed order, since the hardware only cares about the numeric address. Whenever an `EXTI2` or `EXTI3` event occurs, and `IRQ6` is enabled, it jumps to the address at `0x00000058`. The table above ensures that the address of `EXTI2_3_IRQHandler()` goes into the vector table at `0x00000058`.

Digging further in the startup module we find this

```
.weak      EXTI0_1_IRQHandler
.thumb_set EXTI0_1_IRQHandler,Default_Handler

.weak      EXTI2_3_IRQHandler
.thumb_set EXTI2_3_IRQHandler,Default_Handler
```

and this

```
Default_Handler:
Infinite_Loop:
  b Infinite_Loop
```

It means that if there is no definition for `EXTI0_1_IRQHandler()` or `EXTI2_3_IRQHandler()`, then they invoke an infinite loop, good for debugging but nothing else. In order to actually use it, you must override this symbol in your program. If you look at the `GPIO_EXTI` example, it has this handler

```
void EXTI0_1_IRQHandler(void)
{
  HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(USER_BUTTON_PIN);
}
```

defined in `stm32f0xx_it.c` to call `HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler()` when an `EXTI0` interrupt occurs. If you'd like to act on `EXTI3`, then you should have a similar function

```
void EXTI2_3_IRQHandler(void)
{
  HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(3);
}
```

to call `HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler()`.

Comment: Not sure about the handler name.. The HAL has this:-
` void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(uint16_t GPIO_Pin)
 { /* EXTI line interrupt detected */ 
  if(__HAL_GPIO_EXTI_GET_IT(GPIO_Pin) != RESET) { 
   __HAL_GPIO_EXTI_CLEAR_IT(GPIO_Pin); 
   HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(GPIO_Pin); 
   } 
}`

Comment: Sorry about the formatting of previous comment. Am I wrong in assuming that the correct way is to use the interrupt callback?

Comment: I'm pretty sure about the handler name. You should make a connection from the hardware interrupt to the HAL handler function, see the expanded answer.